# Jagged edges when baking in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, baking

[image: Damn jagged]

How do you get rid of jagged edges when baking in cycles? Edges are perfectly smooth when rendering but as soon as i bake it gets jagged. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Increase the resolution of the image you're baking to.

Comment: How many samples are you using?

Comment: @someonewithpc I think the OP wants to know why there is no anti-aliasing. Increasing the resolution won't really fix that, and there should be anti-aliasing with enough samples..

Answer (score 2):

Baking in Cycles does not implement anti-aliasing yet.
Check this thread for more information : https://developer.blender.org/T43388